TypeScript Fails to Infer Specific Generic Types as Expected
I'm currently facing an issue with TypeScript where it seems to be unable to correctly infer types in a specific scenario involving generics, enums, and inheritance.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

enum Status {
  UNDEFINED = 0,
  SUCCESS = 1,
  FAIL = 2,
}

class Result<StatusT extends Status = Status, Data = unknown, Code = string | number> {
  constructor(
    public status?: StatusT,
    public data?: Data,
    public code?: Code,
  ) {}
}

abstract class Task {
  async done(...args: any[]) {
    while (true) {
      const result = await this.execute(...args);
      if (result.status === Status.SUCCESS) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }

  abstract execute(...args: any[]): Promise<{
    [K in Status]: Result<K>;
  }[Status]>
}

class TestTask extends Task {
  // (method) TestTask.execute(): Promise<Result<Status.SUCCESS, {}, number> | Result<Status.FAIL, string, string | number>>
  async execute () {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      return new Result(Status.SUCCESS, {}, 0);
    } else {
      return new Result(Status.FAIL, "error");
    }
  }
}

const test = new TestTask()

// got: `Promise<Result<Status.SUCCESS, unknown, string | number>>`
// but i want: `Promise<Result<Status.SUCCESS, {}, number>>`
test.done();


TypeScript only infers the return type of done() as Promise<Result<Status.SUCCESS, unknown, string | number>>, while I expect it to infer Promise<Result<Status.SUCCESS, {}, number>>.
Why does TypeScript fail to infer the specific generic types as I expect in the TestTask class? Is this a limitation of TypeScript's type inference system, or am I missing something in how I should annotate or structure my types or code?

"however, when calling done(), TypeScript only infers..." please [edit] to show us this in your [mre]. We should be able to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and see the problem leap off the screen at us, because it's the only obvious problem. Right now you haven't reproduced the issue you're describing, you're just talking abou tit.

@jcalz Hi. I've simplified my code and presentation, and you can reproduce it via copy it into typescript playground, thanks.

TypeScript doesn't keep things "hypothetically" generic in the face of possible subclasses. If you want this behavior you'll need to write out the polymorphic type yourself, and use type assertions. Possibly as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks! I will close this thread.


TypeScript doesn't keep things "hypothetically" generic in the face of
possible subclasses. If you want this behavior you'll need to write
out the polymorphic type yourself, and use type assertions. Possibly
as shown in this playground link.

Thank @jcalz for his explanation!

I'm confused. I offered to write an actual answer with an explanation. This is just a copy of my comment, and there's no code here directly, just a playground link. Which is nice in a comment but doesn't suffice as an answer. Shall I write up my own answer?
